# Child class initialization of arguments

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I would like to ask that if we are defining a child class using a base class, why would we need to initialize the arguments in the parent class in `__init__` method. I am similiar to JAVA OOP and as I remember in Java we just add the new arguments in the child class.

If I am wrong about Java too, can somebody please explain the reason to do it? Isn't inheritance something supposed to be make our lives easier with programming.

```
class Car(object):
    condition = "new"
    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.mpg   = mpg

    def display_car(self):
        print "This is a %s %s with %s MPG." % (self.color, self.model, self.mpg)

    def drive_car(self):
        self.condition = "used"

class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg, battery_type):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.mpg = mpg
        self.battery_type = battery_type



my_car = ElectricCar("Auris", "golden", 89, "molten salt")
```

I mean why isn't `self.battery_type = battery_type` inside ElectricCar class is enough for this kind of inheritance?

Comment: In Java, you call the `super` constructor (`super(arg1, arg2, ...)`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can invoke the overridden `__init__` method by using the [`super()` proxy object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super):

```
class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg, battery_type):
        super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(model, color, mpg)
        self.battery_type = battery_type
```

If you are using Python 3, you can omit the class and self references:

```
class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg, battery_type):
        super().__init__(model, color, mpg)
        self.battery_type = battery_type
```

Either way, the `super()` call gives you a proxy object on which you can look up attributes and methods on the whole chain of parent classes; it'll find the next `__init__` method in the chain, then bind it such that you can call it as a regular method.

Comment: So if I would like to call the display_car method of the parent class with an additional feature of its country,
`def display_car(self, country):

super(ElectricCar, self).display_car(country)
self.country = country`
this would be enough then ? for python 2.7

Comment: @Alkadian: the original version doesn't take a `country` argument though.

Comment: along with my new variable, older print which is in the parent class will be there too right?

Comment: @Alkadian: you are just calling a method here; it's just like any other method call, it'll run and do what you defined it to do. As defined it will not also print the country.

Answer (score 3):

You can write :

```
class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg, battery_type):
         super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(model, color, mpg)
         self.battery_type = battery_type
```